# How to post ajax one after another with one submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created some code that call ajax post. Sometime the order of process are right, sometime aren't. I want ajax post that always have the right order, from function 1 to function 4. Every function has different form value, so I really need to fix it.
Can anyone look into my code ?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#unggah<?php echo $mhs?>').submit(function (event) {

//FUNCTION 1

        this.reset();
        $('#loading<?php echo $mhs?>').show();

        var formData = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi1<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData,
            Async:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data1<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data1<?php echo $mhs?>);

        })

        .fail(function (data1<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data1<?php echo $mhs?>);

        });

        event.preventDefault();

//FUNCTION 2

        var formData2 = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi2<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData2,
            Async:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data2<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data2<?php echo $mhs?>);    
        })

        .fail(function (data2<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data2<?php echo $mhs?>);
        });

        event.preventDefault();

//FUNCTION 3        

 var formData3 = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi3<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData3,
            Async:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data3<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data3<?php echo $mhs?>);

        })

        .fail(function (data3<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data3<?php echo $mhs?>);
        });

        event.preventDefault();

// FUNCTION 4

 var formData4 = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi4<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData4,
            Async:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data4<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data4<?php echo $mhs?>);
        })

        .fail(function (data4<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data4<?php echo $mhs?>);
        });
        event.preventDefault(); 
         });
});

        </script>
```

Comment: in your first ajax function, check for status. if it was successful, pass another ajax again.

Comment: Use jQuery Callback Functions ex. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: you can run the second ajax function in the `done` clause of your first ajax function and etc. That will make the order right everytime, as it will wait until the first finishes, until the next runs

Comment: @Richardson.M I'll look into it ..

Comment: The ajax property is `async` with a lowercase `a` not `Async` but in any case, you should't set it to `false` because it will freeze up the page while the request is made.

Comment: @Titus thanks for that tip. I change it to async and my browser suddenly hang. I supposed I just delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write separate function for each ajax request and call one from another's success function.

```
function callAjax3(){
var formData3 = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi3<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData3,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data3<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data3<?php echo $mhs?>);
            callAjax4()  // calling 4th function

        })

        .fail(function (data3<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data3<?php echo $mhs?>);
        });

}

function callAjax2(){
//FUNCTION 2

        var formData2 = {
            'tahun': $('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'jurusan': $('input[name=jurusan<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'posisi': $('input[name=posisi2<?php echo $mhs?>]').val(),
            'tabel': $('input[name=tabel<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData2,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })    
        .done(function (data2<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data2<?php echo $mhs?>);    
              callAjax3();  // calling 3rd function
        })

        .fail(function (data2<?php echo $mhs?>) {
            console.log(data2<?php echo $mhs?>);
        });

}
```

Comment: this look easy, I'll try it

Comment: yes, it is easy and also make your code more clean.

Comment: my browser just suddenly hang after I tried this code, any idea what cause this ?? But the process is run, I can see it in my database ..

Comment: have you return anything from last function

Comment: nevermind, I fixed it. Just delete async:false and everything goes smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest each ajax call in the done() function of the previous one. This way, the n+1th call will only happen once the nth call has completed (successfully).

e.g.

```
$.ajax({data}).done(function() {
    $.ajax({data}).done(function() {...})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.done(` callbacks are called after a request completes successfully.

Make your 2nd request in the `.done(` callback of the 1st one, you 3rd request - in the 2nd request's `.done(` callback, etc.

That will ensure the correct call order.

*... and that's what they call [Pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming))*

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your query correctly then you are looking for a way to submit 2 forms on single submit button click.

You can achieve this by submitting second form manually using jquery .submit() method in success of first form's ajax call.

Let me know if you need updated code for this.