# AJAX post not sending value from form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have weird situation, I have created AJAX post with static value and it's work fine. Now I tried AJAX post with dynamic value from HTML input but doesn't work.
If I tried insert `value="1"` it POST 1 to php.
Can anyone take a look into my code ?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#unggah<?php echo $mhs?>').submit(function (event) {

 var formData = {
            'jmlmhs': $('input[name=jmlmhs]').val(),
            'mulaikul': $('input[name=mulaikul]').val(),
            'akhirkul': $('input[name=akhirkul]').val()
        };

   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })          
 event.preventDefault();

     });

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>" method="POST" role="form" id="unggah<?php echo $mhs?>">
<label for="jmlmhs">Jumlah Mahasiswa Diterima</label>
<div id="jmlmhs" class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jmlmhs" name="jmlmhs" value="">       
</div>

<label for="datePicker">Tanggal Mulai Kuliah</label>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="datePicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mulaikul" value="">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<label for="datePicker1">Tanggal Akhir Kuliah</label>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="datePicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="akhirkul" value="">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>

 <button type="submit" id="button1<?php echo $mhs?>" class="btn btn-primary" ><?php echo $tombol ?></button>

</form>
```

Comment: are you using this form inside any loop?

Comment: yep it is, i'm using loop

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: @BertBijn you can asume the php part is fine. Cause if I change from `value""` to `value"1"` it is post the value.

Comment: If you're using AJAX you don't need the action nor the method in the form, are you sure it's okay your url in the ajax function?, add success to the ajax function to see what happens, because I've tested the code and this works.

Comment: Show us what do `<?php echo $mhs?>` and `<?=base_url()?>operator_pt/unggah/<?php echo $proses.'_'.$CL?>` print.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma the url it is work. The Success function is already on my code but I did not post it, it's just console log. You can see another question that I made if you want to se full code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063527/how-to-post-ajax-one-after-another-with-one-submit-button/43063652?noredirect=1#comment73211914_43063652)

Comment: @SebastiánPalma if you want to look up into the console log, here the screenshoot [link screenshoot](http://imgur.com/yGNGjE6). I have several post with static value, it is posted correctly, Only value from HTML that did not post

Comment: The `name` attributes of your inputs aren't repeated?, as they say in the past question, maybe they need to be dynamic as in `$('input[name=tahun<?php echo $mhs?>]').val()`.

Comment: I just fixed it, just delete `this.reset();` and everything goes smooth. I don't even know why I add `this.reset();` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the name in the css selector:

```
 var formData = {
    'jmlmhs': $('input[name="jmlmhs"]').val(),
    'mulaikul': $('input[name="mulaikul"]').val(),
    'akhirkul': $('input[name="akhirkul"]').val()
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, just delete `this.reset();` and everything goes smooth. I don't even know why I add `this.reset();` in the first place. I forget to insert `this.reset();` code on the question. So people can't help me either.

Comment: I didn't see your self answer.